# pip install failing due to no 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found

Tags: python, jenkins, pip

I have a sh script line (as part of a Jenkinsfile groovy script) which does

```
    sh "python3 -m venv venv"
    sh "source venv/bin/activate"
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: XXXXXXX,
                                          usernameVariable: 'XXXXXXX',
                                          passwordVariable: 'XXXXXXX')]) {
    sh "pip install --extra-index-url 'https://${XXXXXXX}:${XXXXXX}@atifactory-url-base/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-release-local/simple' -e ."
    }
    
    sh "pip freeze >> requirements.txt"
```

However, above fails with

```
ERROR: file:///home/jenkins/workspace/XXXXXXXXXXX does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
```

The project I have has no setup.py or requirements.txt file at the top level - how can I do this without adding the current python project for installation using `-e`?

Comment: Are you missing a closing quote `'` after the URL? -- If there is no `setup.py` nor `pyproject.toml` than what is it that you want to install?

Comment: Error is because the `-e` flag (`--editable`) which is trying to Install a project in editable mode from a local project path or a VCS url - and you are passing `.` (local folder) which doesn't contain the relevant file and thats the exception.

Comment: @sinoroc        apologies - I have updated my question - hopefully that give more context

Comment: If your project is not a valid package, you can't `pip install` it. It needs to have either of those two files in order to be installable.

Comment: "The project I have has no setup.py or requirements.txt file at the top level" `requirements.txt` is irrelevant, but you **must** have either `setup.py` or `pyproject.toml` - like the error message tells you. These are files that `pip install` uses in order to understand how to install the code. Please read https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/ to understand how packaging works in Python. If it is someone else's code, then either it was deliberately not designed to be installed (because it exists to be a top-level script) or it was not properly packaged (open a Github issue about it).

Comment: As an aside, `sh "source venv/bin/activate"` activates the virtual environment, then immediately exits, returning you to a state where it is not active. If you want the `pip install` to run in the virtual environment, use `venv/bin/pip install` and probably take out the useless explicit `activate`.

Comment: (Also, `source` is not valid `sh` syntax; presumably you are really running `bash`; but then your code should properly require Bash, not proceed on the assumption that `sh` will always be Bash. See also [Difference between Bash and `sh`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash))

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you add a `pip install` command in a Dockerfile that doesn't have setup.py copied into its context, such as a VSCode dev container. Put the pip call in the `postCreateCommand` instead.