# Vertex AI custom job to run python-module with pre-built containers (using gcloud CLI)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, containers, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am updating a model that is previously running on gcp `ai-platform` to `vertex ai` [1, 2].

The settings that I am looking for are as below.

- `Vertex AI custom job` with `pre-built containers` (using `gcloud CLI)`
- to run a custom `python-module` which contains the code of the training phase of our model

**Can someone help me if there is something wrong with the below sequence of the task?**

It does not seem the python module is the cause of the problem since it is the same code that is currently running well with `ai-platform`.

##### Python3 module packaging

```bash
# simplified python module structure
# ./vertex-ai-poc
# ├── __init__.py
# ├── trainer
# │   ├── __init__.py
# │   └── task.py
# └── setup.py

python3 ./[PATH]/vertex-ai-poc/setup.py sdist --formats=gztar
# -> dist generated

gsutil cp dist/trainer-0.2.tar.gz gs://[PROJECT_ID]/vertex-ai-poc/trainer-0.2.tar.gz
# -> uploaded correctly
```

##### Submit Custom Job

```
gcloud ai custom-jobs create \
    --region us-central1 \
    --display-name=vertex-ai-poc \
    --project=[PROJECT_ID] \
    --python-package-uris='gs://[PROJECT_ID]/vertex-ai-poc/trainer-0.2.tar.gz' \
    --worker-pool-spec=machine-type=e2-standard-4,replica-count=1,executor-image-uri='us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/training/tf-cpu.2-7:latest',python-module=trainer.task
```

However, I am encountering the below errors.

##### Error Messages

> file:///user_dir/trainer-0.2.tar.gz does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.

*c.f. I am noticing `file:///` with 3 slashes. And belive there is something to do with docker.* [3]

[image]

[image]

References

- [1][Create custom training jobs](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/create-custom-job)
- [2][gcloud ai custom-jobs create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai/custom-jobs/create)
- [3][pip install failing due to no 'setup.pyz' nor 'pyproject.toml' found - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71681663/pip-install-failing-due-to-no-setup-py-nor-pyproject-toml-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up fixing the problem. I'll share the situation for those of you with a similar error. The problem was that I wasn't using `find_packages()` correctly.

First, there are three possible ways of submitting custom vertex-ai jobs.

1. auto packaging
2. without auto packaging - Custom container image
3. without auto packaging - Python App

   1. using `local-package-path` param
   2. using `--python-package-uris` flag

(I believe) Method 1, 2, and 3.1 build docker images in the **local machine** and submit the built image to `vertex-ai`. Method 3.2 simply uses a pre-built container and combines python packages at `executor-image-uri` in `vertex-ai`.

** The problem was that when I run the below command to generate the dist package, I ran it from `../..` with `./[PATH]/.` and ended up not correctly getting the `find_packages()` values which lead to both 3.1 and 3.2 methods not correctly running.

```bash
# Error: python3 ./[PATH]/vertex-ai-poc/setup.py sdist --formats=gztar`
python3 ./setup.py sdist --formats=gztar`
```

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='trainer',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),  # <-- HERE
    include_package_data=True,
)
```

The fixed version of local-package and external uris end up making the below script work.

###### 3.1 without auto packaging - Python App - using `local-package-path` param

```
gcloud ai custom-jobs create \
    --region us-central1 \
    --display-name=vertex-ai-poc \
    --project=[PROJECT_ID] \
    --worker-pool-spec=machine-type=e2-standard-4,replica-count=1,executor-image-uri='us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/training/tf-cpu.2-7:latest',script=task.py,local-package-path=vertex-ai-poc/trainer
```

###### 3.2 Without auto packaging - Python App - using `--python-package-uris` flag

```
gcloud ai custom-jobs create \
    --region us-central1 \
    --display-name=vertex-ai-poc \
    --project=[PROJECT_ID] \
    --python-package-uris='gs://[PROJECT_ID]/vertex-ai-poc/trainer-0.1.tar.gz' \
    --worker-pool-spec=machine-type=e2-standard-4,replica-count=1,executor-image-uri='us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/training/tf-cpu.2-7:latest',python-module=trainer.task
```

###### Results

[image]